# SVM for text classification - tutorial on machine learning? How do I get started?

Tags: text, machine-learning, nlp, classification

I'm looking for a really good tutorial on machine learning for text classification perhaps using Support vector machine (SVM) or other appropriate technology for large-scale supervised text classification. If there isn't a great tutorial, can anyone give me pointers to how a beginner should get started and do a good job with things like feature detection for English language Text Classification.

Books, articles, anything that can help beginners get started would be super helpful!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

In its classical flavour the Support Vector Machine (SVM) is a binary classifier (i.e., it solves classification problems involving two classes). However, it can be also used to solve multi-class classification problems by applying techniques likes One versus One, One Versus All or Error Correcting Output Codes [[Alwein et al.]](http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/AllweinSS00.pdf). Also recently, a new modification of the classical SVM the multiclass-SVM allows to solve directly multi-class classification problems [[Crammer et al.]](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume2/crammer01a/crammer01a.pdf).

Now as far as it concerns document classification, your main problem is feature extraction (i.e., how to acquire certain classification features from your documents). This is not a trivial task and there's a batch of bibliography on the topic (e.g., [[Rehman et al.]](http://www.taibahu.edu.sa/iccit/allICCITpapers/pdf/p231-rehman.pdf), [[Lewis]](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/H/H92/H92-1041.pdf)).

Once you've overcome the obstacle of feature extraction, and have labeled and placed your document samples in a feature space you can apply any classification algorithm like SVMs, AdaBoost e.t.c.

Introductory books on machine learning:
[[Flach]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107422221), [[Mohri]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026201825X), [[Alpaydin]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/026201243X), [[Bishop]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387310738), [[Hastie]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387848576)

Books specific for SVMs:
[[Schlkopf]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262194759), [[Cristianini]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521780195)

Some specific bibliography on document classification and SVMs:
[[Miner et al.]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/012386979X), [[Srivastava et al.]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1420059408), [[Weiss et al.]](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849962251), [[Pilászy]](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.106.8812&rep=rep1&type=pdf), [[Joachims]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_98a.pdf), [[Joachims01]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_01a.pdf), [[Joachims97]](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/publications/joachims_97b.pdf), [[Sassano]](http://aclweb.org/anthology//W/W03/W03-1027.pdf)